# How to use Linq to update fields in a list based on another list joined by id

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of counter objects and a list of deltas.
Is there a way using Linq to update the counter lists fields using data from the delta while joining by Id.

Here is a cut down code sample.

```
class Counter
{
    public int Id;
    public int A;
    public int B;
}

class Delta
{
    public int Id;
    public int ADelta;
    public int BDelta;
}

IList<Counter> counters = new List<Counter>()
{
    new Counter{Id=1, A=0, B=5},
    new Counter{Id=2, A=0, B=0},
    new Counter{Id=3, A=5, B=0}
};

IList<Delta> deltas = new List<Delta>()
{
    new Delta(){Id=1, ADelta=5, BDelta = 5},
    new Delta(){Id=3, ADelta=0, BDelta = 10}
};
```

It would join by id and the counters would end up as:

```
Counter{Id=1, A=5, B=10}
Counter{Id=2, A=0, B=0}
Counter{Id=3, A=5, B=10}
```

Comment: What if there is more than one delta corresponding to counter?

Comment: In the full application there is only one delta per counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq is for querying, not for updating existing instances. I suggest you to create dictionary for deltas and then use simple foreach to update existing counters:

```
var deltasById = deltas.ToDictionary(d => d.Id);

foreach (var counter in counters)
{
    Delta delta;
    if (!deltasById.TryGetValue(counter.Id, out delta))
        continue;

    counter.A += delta.ADelta;
    counter.B += delta.BDelta;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    counters = counters.Select(c =>
                                   {
                                       var delta = deltas.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id == c.Id);
                                       return new Counter
                                                  {
                                                      Id = c.Id,
                                                      A = c.A + (delta != null ? delta.ADelta : 0),
                                                      B = c.B + (delta != null ? delta.BDelta : 0)
                                                  };
                                   }).ToList();
```